# Changing individual movieclip's frame rate with TweenMax

Tags: actionscript-3

My aim is to change the frame rates of my individual (looping) movie clips through clickable controls (slow/med/fast). I've heard it isnt possible to achieve this through as3/flash alone, so I've tried greensock's TweenMax... However I can't seem to figure out how to do this. Is there anyone that could help?

```
box1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, box1down);
function box1down(event:MouseEvent):void {

//FRAMERATE CODE HERE

}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the API doc for TweenMax: http://www.greensock.com/as/docs/tween/com/greensock/TweenMax.html

If you have multiple movieclips that you are trying to control, you can just create an abstract class with the functionality you want and extend that class. So something like:

```
public class ControlledMovieClip extends MovieClip {

    public function ControlledMovieClip() {
        stop();
    }

    public function animate(frameRateInSeconds:Number):void {            
        TweenMax.to(this, frameRateInSeconds, { frame: this.totalFrames - 1, repeat: -1, ease: Linear.easeNone });
    }
}
```

Have all your movieclips that are looping extend that class, and then you could call the animate function on the objects in your `box1down` event handler.

I haven't tested that code so you might need a `gotoAndStop(1)` at the end of each iteration.

Comment: thanks for the help :) i guess i've got a lot more learning to do, this is still quite hard for me to understand! i really appreciate the help though...

Answer (score 1):

It's possible through Actionscript alone it just requires you to handle the frame progression yourself (instead of using mc.play() you stop the movieclip and call nextFrame() yourself).

Lets say a Movieclip (myMC) has 20 frames of animation. To manually run the animation at normal speed you simply call `myMC.nextFrame();` on every frame of your project (using an `ENTER_FRAME` listener for example).

To have the animation run at half speed you can use a frame count and a frame trigger:

```
var frameTick = 0;
var frameAnimTrigger = 2;

function Update(e:Event):void
{
  frameTick++;
  if(frameTick == frameAnimTrigger)
  {
    myMC.nextFrame();
    frameTick = 0;
  }
}
```

Because `nextFrame` is only called every other frame the animation appears to run at half speed.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm not sure I completely understand though. Does this mean it will be skipping frames creating the illusion of it running at half the speed?

Comment: No it won't skip frames.  A basic `ENTER_FRAME` listener is called every single frame so calling a movieclips `nextFrame()` function every single frame is equivalent to just calling `play()` and it will run at normal speed.  If you call `nextFrame()` every OTHER frame, as noted above, it still plays every frame of the movieclip, but instead of progressing to the next frame of the movieclip when `ENTER_FRAME` occurs it will only progress EVERY OTHER time `ENTER_FRAME` occurs.